# Keeping variables from PHP while loop

Tags: php, javascript

I have been looking all over for a way to do this.

I use a PHP while loop to get some variables from a database:

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$id = $row["ID"];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function go_there()
{
var id= "<?php echo $id ?>"
var where_to= confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
 if (where_to== true)
 {
   window.location="index.php?p=delete&id=" + id;
 }
 else
 {

  }
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
<td><form><INPUT TYPE="button" value="Go!" onClick="go_there()"></form></td></tr>
<? } //end while
?>
```

Sometimes i get 10 results, and i make 10 Go! bottoms. But when i come to the delete page, the $is variable is off cause the same as the last result, no matter witch of the bottoms i press..

Any ideas on how to get around that, so i get the confirm box, and still keep the right id to be deleted?

Comment: what is your question/problem

Comment: Make your `go_there` a parametrized function, taking $id as param; make its invokation `onclick` parametrized as well. Or even better, assign some value to `button` itself, then check this value within the function.

Comment: The "language" attribute is deprecated, assuming an HTML5 document. Use `<script type="text/javascript">` or just `<script>` tags.

Comment: raina77ow i dont really know what you are saying. Im kinda n00b when it comes to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a global function called "go_there" for each entry, so only the last one will remain.  Instead of that, create just **one** function, and fetch the "id" value from an attribute on the button.

```
function go_there(button)
{
  var id= button.getAttribute("data-id");
  var where_to= confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
  if (where_to== true)
  {
    window.location="index.php?p=delete&id=" + id;
  }
}
```

Then:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" value="Go!" onClick="go_there(this)" data-id="<?php echo $id ?>">
```

Comment: Great, this seems to work. What do i do if i want to pass in more variables?

Comment: Thanx a lot, this made it work for me. I wish i could vote this answer up, but i need a rep before i can do that sorry :) But thanks a lot, you saved my day...

Comment: @MortenBallePetersen You don't need to vote it up, just accept it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you're creating your javascript function in your loop as well so it only fires one of them (you're creating multiple functions with the same name. How is it supposed to know which one to use). You should create 1 javascript function and pass the id into it as a a parameter

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function go_there(id)
{

 var where_to= confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
 if (where_to== true)
 {
   window.location="index.php?p=delete&id=" + id;
 }
 else
 {

  }
 }

 </SCRIPT>
 <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$id = $row["ID"];

 echo '<td><form><INPUT TYPE="button" value="Go!" onClick="go_there(<?php echo $id; ?>)"></form></td></tr>'
 } //end while
 ?>
```

Comment: Ill try that. Then i can have the javascript in my <head>

Answer (score 0):

Overall this is a poor way to do this. You should avoid wrtiting handlers inline unless you have a specific case where it is the only way. Much better if you attach a handler to the elements in questions ([working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QVAjC/) - for firefox anyhow...):

```
<!-- output our inputs with the id value in an attribute data-id-value -->
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)): $id = $row["ID"]; ?>
   <td><form><INPUT class="go-button" TYPE="button" value="Go!" data-id-value="<?php echo $id ?>"></form></td></tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var goButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input.go-button'), // select all out buttons
       // define our handler function
       goThere = function (event) {

            // get the id the we encoded from php from our data attr
            var id = event.target.getAttribute('data-id-value');

            if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {

                // if confirm is true then redirect to the delete url
                window.location = "index.php?p=delete&id=" + id;
            }
       };

   // loop over the buttons and attach the handler
   for (var i = 0; i < goButtons.length; i++) {
       goButtons[i].addEventListener('click', goThere);
   }
</script>
```

The issue here is that that isnt necessarily cross browser. Thats typically one of the reasons people use libraries like jQuery or similar so that they don't have to normalize dom querying and listener attachment.

Comment: How do you do this with post method?

Comment: Instead of using `window.location` you would just submit the form with the proper post value to make it do the delete or by changing the `action` attribute to the delete URL before doing the submit.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a corrected script.

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$id = $row["ID"];
?>      
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
function go_there()
{
var id= "<?php echo $id ?>"
var where_to= confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
 if (where_to == true)
 {
   window.location="index.php?p=delete&id=" + id;
 }
 else
 {

  }
}
-->
</SCRIPT>
  <td><form><INPUT TYPE="button" value="Go!" onClick="go_there()"></form></td></tr>
```

Your button will not work because you have added the comment markers `<!--` and `-->` to the function. If you want help with that then please comment.

Also, can you clarify you're issue in the comments? We can help you better then.

Comment: HTML comments around a script won't cause a problem, though there's no point to it in 2013.

Comment: I edited the script a little to not have the whole thing for you guys to read, the bottoms are working, but my problem is the var id="<?php echo $id ?>" gets changed for every time the while loop goes, so then i press one of the bottoms i get, the is it will delete is always the id of the last id in the mysql statement

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry but I really don't understand your question. And please do not mark me down because this question wasn't really explained very well!